# How to insert 100s of values to a db if I am using sqlalchemy and mysql for python flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to flask. So I came to know about sql alchemy. Can someone explain me how to use it properly?
Is it like, we need to create a Mysql db first and connect to flask or is everything done through sqlalchemy?
or whatever be the tables in mysql,same have to be represented in models.py???
I tried many tutorials but nothing explains the same.

Thanks in advnce

Comment: Hi newbie, don't simply ask for explanation or tutorial kinds of thing here. Try to show your code here with explanation and the expected output...so that the community will help you very well.

Comment: i am not able to understand the use of sqlalachemy..i tried many tutorials,without understanding i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, to insert 100s of value a once use BULK operations like `add_all` (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations)

If you don't know Sqlalchemy go here http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html

```
from app import session
from models import User

objects = [User(name="u1"), User(name="u2"), User(name="u3")]
session.add_all(objects)
session.commit()
```

Comment: the data is in sql file